# No sound ASUS F554L - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, asus-laptop

I have no sound coming from my ASUS F554LD laptop that I upgraded to windows10.

I checked on the site for drivers and they dont have a windows 10 sound driver yet, would this be my problem?

Comment: What's your sound codec? I'd guess the windows 8 drivers would work. What does device manager say?

Comment: I've had a similar issue with my Via drivers for years on Windows 10.
It seems that there is a driver for Via audio devices that fixed it for me now. Go to http://download.viatech.com/en/support/driversSelect.jsp and select Windows 10 (only one driver named Vinyl is available), download that and run the setup. Fixed everything for me

Answer (score 2):

This fixed my sound problem, after updating to Windows 10:

1- In Search Windows, type **Sound**.

2- Under the Playback tab, double click on **Speakers**.

3- Go to the Advanced tab.

4- In the Default format, change the Bit and Hz of your speaker and Test. Choose a range that you can hear the speakers and click Apply.

5- Done.

Source:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/c00d1199

Answer (score 0):

Go to sounds Click configure follows the steps click next, next etc. then go to properties in the enhancements section click on restore defaults, then go advance section an see if you can test the sound if not try changing the format. it worked for me. i hope it helps you.

Comment: when i clicked test it came up with "couldn't test sound" something along those lines. I just ended up reinstalling the driver and it worked. My aux port still doesn't work though and hasn't for a few weeks (even before win10 upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

what I ended up having to do to fix it was to go in and uninstall and then reinstall the VIA HD Audio drivers, using the ones already on the system. Once I did that, my speakers work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the driver by going into Device Manager under Settings, then Sound, Video and Game Controllers.  Under Realtek High Definition Audio there was the option under Driver to Update, which reinstalled the driver and the sound worked straightaway.